# Safari: search hidden text

Tags: search, safari

I have couple of block on the page which are hidden. So, when user tries to search text on the page using build-in browser search mechanism safari shows these hidden blocks. I dont want to allow user see these blocks before special event happened. Is there anyone who had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you hiding it with css: ?

```
display: none;
```

I doubt you can force the browser to change it's behaviour but if the div or span or whatever element contains the text, is with "display: none" safari shouldn't find it.

Comment: it's not work. For example, if you have a slider with big element which wrapped by div (or another tag) with overflow hidden.